# Creating a Facebook Login for my site

Tags: facebook-login

I just got my website, www.anointedmanna.com and would like to add a facebook login option for my guests.  I have followed all of the steps but I am getting errors.  Facebook development assisted me to a point but I don't understand how to fix this.

According to facebook development the problem with this is issue is as follows:

> APP_ID in this URL needs to be replaced with your actual app ID and not left that way.

I don't know what this means, can anyone explain?  Or is there a step by step option to assist with setting all of this up? it is quite confusing

Comment: Have you gone through this documentation ? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/

When you click [Get Code], where it says `APP_ID` you need to replace that with your facebook app's app id.